# Where does the Step-Down Convertor used as compare to RECOM DC/DC converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, electromagnetic, electrolytic-capacitor, step-down, step-up

I am reading Step-Down converter and given the circuit below, which is a step down converter. It consists of a MOSFET, inductor, diode, capacitor

[image]

And if I compare it with RECOM component DC/DC converter.

[image]

[image]

Both are very different circuits. I am wondering why it is different, and where does the Step-Down converter (with MOSFET, diode, capacitor, inductor) used in the circuit.

Comment: The first circuit is incomplete as there’s nothing controlling the FET.  The second is incomplete as it doesn’t show the internals of the converter, just the input filtering components.  There’s no reason to expect them to be similar at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DC/DC converter module has a step down converter in it.

It includes all the required electronics, such as inductors, switching elements and diodes, in addition to control feedback elements for setting the voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean the "DC/DC converter module" is RECOM 78C5.0-1.0 has already all the required electronics (inductors, switching elements, diodes) inside?
So I do not need to design a Buck Convertor (first diagram) above?

Sorry, I could not catch the meaning

Comment: Your step down converter schematic is not complete. 1. nothing drives the gate of the transistor. 2. there is no feedback loop. It is sort of an ideal, simplified schema. The Recom part is an actual product.

Comment: Yes. The diagram is a generic block diagram for a concept of a step down converter. The Recom module is a finished physical device that implements it.

Comment: @Justme Thank you for your reply. So I just use the Recom module and follow the datasheet will do? Because in my work, I saw my colleague use Recom module only in his diagram. But during the job interview, they asked me the "Generic Block Diagram of step down converter".